# Density of odd vs even group orders that are not forced to be simple by Sylow's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

In Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra text, I've just solved the following two Exercises:

> Write a computer program which
>
> (i) gives each odd number $n<10,000$ that is not a power of a prime and for each prime divisor $p$ of $n$ the corresponding $n_p$ is not forced to be 1 for all groups of order $n$ by the congruence condition of Sylow's Theorem and
>
> (ii) gives for each $n$ in $(i)$ the factorization of $n$ into prime powers and gives the list of all permissible values of $n_p$ for all primes $p$ dividing $n$ (i.e., those values not ruled out by Part 3 of Sylow's Theorem).

and

> Carry out the same process as in the preceding exercise for all even numbers less than $1000$. *Explain the relative lengths of the lists versus the number of integers tested.*

The solutions can be found [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/06/05/simple-group-order-candidates-among-the-odd-integers-less-than-10000/) and [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/simple-group-order-candidates-among-the-even-integers-less-than-1000/). It appears that there are $60$ odd candidates in the interval $[1,10,000]$ and $85$ even candidates in the interval $[1,1000]$.

My problem is providing the explanation required for the last part of the second Exercise.

I could find some simple arguments as for why the second list is longer:

- The only even prime powers are powers of $2$, so less numbers are eliminated in the even case.
- For any group $G$ of even order $n$ which is not a power of $2$, Part 3 of Sylow's Theorem leaves all divisors of the index of a Sylow 2-subgroup as possible values for $n_2(G)$. In other words, $n_2$ never eliminates $n$ from the list.

Are these two arguments sufficient to justify the higher density of the even orders? To be more quantitative, The densities are $\frac{60}{10,000}$ for the odd orders vs $\frac{85}{1,000}$ for the even orders. Taking the ratio of the latter by the former makes it seem like the even orders are $\approx 14.2$ times denser.

Can anyone help me give a better explanation as for why the even orders are that much more dense than the odd ones?

Thank you!

Comment: For odd primes $p$ the number $p+1$ is even. On one hand the same holds for $3p+1, 5p+1, \dots$, so you loose many possible $n_p$'s. On the other hand you have for small $p$ a good chance that $p+1$ is twice a prime or more generally a small multiple of a prime.

Comment: How does the statistic look for multiples of 3 versus non-multiples?

Answer (score 0):

Then $n=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}$ and $n_{p}=kp+1$ such that $n_{p}$ divides $n/p^{\alpha}$ and there is the table of $60$ entries
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
    n   &   p\quad\alpha_{p}    &   p\quad k\\\hline
 105 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 315 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 351 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 495 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 18 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 525 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 735 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 16 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 945 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 1053 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 1365 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 30 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 18 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 13 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1485 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 18 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 1575 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 32 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 1755 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 70 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 1785 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 17 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 28 \\
 3 & 198 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 10 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 12 \\
 17 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2025 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 5 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2205 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 16 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 88 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2457 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 30 \\
 7 & 50 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2475 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2625 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 3 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2775 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 37 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 12 \\
 3 & 308 \\
 5 & 22 \\
 37 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2835 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 16 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2907 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 17 & 1 \\
 19 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6 \\
 17 & 10 \\
 19 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 3159 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 5 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 3393 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 13 & 1 \\
 29 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 13 & 20 \\
 29 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 3465 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 3 & 128 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 46 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 14 \\
 11 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 3675 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 16 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 3 & 408 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 3875 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 3 \\
 31 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 6 \\
 31 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4095 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 30 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 18 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 13 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4125 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 3 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 3 & 458 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 34 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4389 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
 19 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 6 \\
 3 & 44 \\
 7 & 8 \\
 11 & 12 \\
 19 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4455 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 18 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 5 & 16 \\
 5 & 178 \\
 11 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4563 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 56 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4725 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 32 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4851 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 16 \\
 7 & 14 \\
 11 & 40 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 5103 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 7 & 104 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 5145 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 16 \\
 3 & 114 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 5265 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 16 \\
 5 & 70 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 5313 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
 23 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 84 \\
 3 & 590 \\
 7 & 36 \\
 11 & 2 \\
 23 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5355 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 17 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 28 \\
 3 & 198 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 10 \\
 5 & 214 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 12 \\
 17 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 5445 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 11 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 18 \\
 3 & 40 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 5 & 24 \\
 11 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6075 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 5 \\
 5 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 5 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6375 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 3 \\
 17 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 28 \\
 3 & 708 \\
 5 & 10 \\
 17 & 22 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6435 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 3 & 238 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 4 \\
 13 & 38 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6545 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
 17 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 2 \\
 7 & 12 \\
 11 & 54 \\
 17 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6615 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 16 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 88 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6669 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 13 & 1 \\
 19 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 6 \\
 3 & 82 \\
 13 & 2 \\
 19 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 6825 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 30 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 3 & 108 \\
 3 & 758 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 18 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 13 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 7371 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 30 \\
 7 & 50 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 7425 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 11 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 7875 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 3 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 32 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 8325 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 37 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 12 \\
 3 & 308 \\
 5 & 22 \\
 37 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 8505 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 5 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 16 \\
 5 & 340 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 8721 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 17 & 1 \\
 19 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6 \\
 17 & 10 \\
 19 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 8775 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 108 \\
 5 & 70 \\
 13 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 8883 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 47 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 7 & 20 \\
 47 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 8925 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 17 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 8 \\
 3 & 28 \\
 3 & 58 \\
 3 & 198 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 10 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 12 \\
 7 & 182 \\
 17 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 9045 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 3 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 67 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 22 \\
 5 & 40 \\
 67 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 9405 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 11 & 1 \\
 19 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 3 & 348 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 5 & 34 \\
 5 & 376 \\
 11 & 4 \\
 19 & 26 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 9477 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
 13 & 2 \\
 13 & 56 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 9555 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 16 \\
 3 & 30 \\
 3 & 212 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 18 \\
 5 & 382 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 13 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 9765 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 31 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 10 \\
 3 & 72 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 \\
 5 & 130 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 7 & 22 \\
 31 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

The shorter list of evens produces $85$ entries compared to the longer list of odds which produces $60$ entries. The $4$ possible entries of the odds (entries less than $500$) produce $6$ entries on the evens list. Note that many more combinations of odd primes less than $500$ become possible in combination with various powers of $2$. Thus the difference in length of the lists. It is interesting to create a list of the odd prime factorizations less than $500$ and the minimal power of $2$ for which they become solutions such that the overall number is less than $1000$. Let $k$ be the minimal power and $n$ be the the number of powers $k,k+1,\ldots$ that yield solutions less than $1000$. Then there is the table
\begin{align*}
    \begin{array}{cccc}
        \text{Odd factors}    &   k   &   n   &   \text{Solutions}\\\hline
      3   &  2  &   7   &   12,24,48,96,192,384,768\\
      3\cdot 5   &  1   &   6   &   30,60,120,240,480,960\\
      3^{2}   &  2  &   5   &   36,72,144,288,576\\
      7   &  3  &   5   &   56,112,224,448,896\\
      5   &  4  &   4   &   80,160,320,640\\
      3^{2}\cdot 5   &  1   &   4   &   90,180,360,720\\
      3^{3}   &  2  &   4   &   108,216,432,864\\
      3\cdot 11   &  2  &   3   &   132,264,528\\
      3\cdot 5^{2}   &  1  &   3   &   150,300,600\\
      3\cdot 7   &  3  &   3   &   168,336,672\\
      3\cdot 5\cdot 7   &  1  &   3   &   210,420,840\\
      3^{2}\cdot 7   &  2  &   2   &   252,504\\
      3^{3}\cdot 5   &  1  &   2   &   270,540\\
      5\cdot 7   &  3  &   2   &   280,560\\
      3^{2}\cdot 17   &  1  &   2   &   306,612\\
      3^{4}   &  2  &   2   &   324,648\\
      5\cdot 19   &  2  &   2   &   380,760\\
      7^{2}   &  3  &   2   &   392,784\\
      3^{2}\cdot 11   &  2  &   2   &   396,792\\
      5^{2}   &  4  &   2   &   400,800\\
      3^{2}\cdot 5^{2}   &  1  &   2   &   450,900\\
      5\cdot 13   &  3  &   1   &   520\\
      3\cdot 7\cdot 13   &  1  &   1   &   546\\
      3\cdot 23   &  3  &   1   &   552\\
      7\cdot 11   &  3  &   1   &   616\\
      3^{2}\cdot 5\cdot 7   &  1   &   1   &   630\\
      3\cdot 5\cdot 11   &  2   &   1   &   660\\
      3^{3}\cdot 13   &  1  &   1   &   702\\
      7\cdot 13   &  3  &   1   &   728\\
      3\cdot 5^{3}   &  1  &   1   &   750\\
      3^{3}\cdot 7   &  2  &   1   &   756\\
      3^{4}\cdot 5   &  1  &   1   &   810\\
      3\cdot 11\cdot 13   &  1  &   1   &   858\\
      3\cdot 5\cdot 29   &  1  &   1   &   870\\
      3^{3}\cdot 17   &  1  &   1   &   918\\
      3\cdot 7\cdot 11   &  2  &   1   &   924\\
      3^{5}   &  2  &   1   &   972\\
      3^{2}\cdot 5\cdot 11   &  1   &   1   &   990\\
      31   &  5   &   1   &   992\\\hline
        &   &   85
    \end{array}
\end{align*}
Observe that only the odd factorizations $3\cdot 5\cdot 7$, $3^{2}\cdot 5\cdot 7$, $3^{3}\cdot 13$, and $3^{2}\cdot 5\cdot 11$ appeared on the list from Exercise~4.5.47.